# Is it possible JPA/Hibernate use ManyToOne with only parent field?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jackson, self-reference

I try make relationship between my Menus entity with only one field: ***Parent***

I do this like:

```
@Entity
@Table
@Getter @Setter
public class ProductCategory extends BaseEntity {
    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
    private ProductCategory parent;
}
```

but I got *Direct self-reference leading to cycle* error. Is it possible use only one field for relation? or I must define ***child*** field as JsonManagedReference?

Comment: Share the detailed stack trace.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HcKq6t2n

Comment: Looks to be associated to jackson. What do you mean with "only one field for relation" ?

Comment: in many to one, we define a field on parent (by type collection), then in child define a field as parent type. yes? but I want define parent field in child entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made same thing once with @OneToMany as below :

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {
    @JsonProperty("Id")
    @Id
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("Code")
    private String code;

    @JsonProperty("Name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("ParentId")
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private Integer parent;

    @JsonProperty("NewAdminId")
    private int newAdminId;

    @JsonProperty("VolumetricWeight")
    @Column(name = "volumetricWeight")
    private Float volumetricWeight = 0.0f;

    @JsonProperty("Nodes")
    @OneToMany(
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    private List<Category> categories;


    public Category(int id, String code, String name, int newAdminId, List<Category> categories) {
        this.id = id;
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.newAdminId = newAdminId;
        this.categories = categories;
    }
}
```

Test for proving that works:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
public class CategoryRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private CategoryRepository categoryRepository;

    @Test
    public void when_findAll_with_specification_returnTopCategory() {

        Category topRoot = CategoryBuilder.aCategory()
                .code("1")
                .id(1)
                .name("test root category")
                .newAdminId(1)
                .parent(null)
                .build();

        Category child = CategoryBuilder.aCategory()
                .code("2")
                .id(2)
                .name("test child category")
                .newAdminId(2)
                .parent(1)
                .build();

        entityManager.persistAndFlush(topRoot);
        entityManager.persistAndFlush(child);

        List<Category> found = categoryRepository.findAll(isTopRoot());

        assertThat(found).hasSize(1);
        assertThat(found.get(0)).isEqualTo(topRoot);
    }
}
```

Comment: No dude, This make Infinite recursion between parent and childes!

you must use @ JsonManagedReference and @ JsonBackReference to avoid this error.

Comment: Well I updated the answer, added some unit test. Actually I don't get recursion error with provided code.

Comment: yes, your solution is correct! but i define a field as parent ( private Category parent; ) that make error. thanks @emre

Comment: I'm glad to help you